# adding row to the QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I have **QStandardItemModel** and the data are represented as lists

```
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
myrow = [1, "B"]
```

My first solution how to add the row was with function **setData()**

```
model.insertRow(0)
for i,item in enumerate(myrow):
    model.setData(model.index(0, i), item)
```

But it's extremely slow and I have performance problems already for 500 rows, it takes 1 second.

Than I've tried adding whole row at once.

```
model.insertRow(0, [QtGui.QStandardItem(item) for item in myrow ])
```

It is more faster, but it doesn't work properly.

```
print "setData() 2.row - ",model.data(model.index(1,0)).toInt()
print "insertRow() 1.row - ",model.data(model.index(0,0)).toInt()
```

And I get different outputs.

```
 setData() 2.row - (1, True)
 insertRow() 1.row - (0, False)
```

any Idea why?
Is there any other way how to add whole row to the model?

Comment: Why are you using `toInt()` given one piece of data is a string?

Comment: The input is number 1, so I need to keep the item as a number in my model. After reading the data from my model I make some calculation.